# Will there be any problem if page having errors in Google structured data?

Tags: structured-data

I have applied the JSON-LD structured data for Product schema. I have just checked that a few fields are required by Google Guidelines. ( https://share.getcloudapp.com/7Ku09XQQ )

Will it be accepted by Google? Or will there be any penalty or any issue with such errors/warnings/recommended fields?

Answer (score 1):

Google's guidelines relate to eligibility for rich snippets. Their testing tools also show errors and warnings related to issues that can mean those rich snippets may not show.

There is no penalty.